# Best practice for storing x y coordinates? double[] array or create a Coordinate class?

Tags: java, coordinates

What is the best way to store x y coordinates in a Model? As a `double[]` array? Or to have a separate Coordinate class:

```
   public class Coordinate {

    private double x;
    private double y;
```

The coordinates will be later converted to Point2D and used in a drawing application.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your project I say: Use a class. Look for information about `Primitive Obsession`.

Comment: You could create a `record`.

Comment: How are you using the data?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

If your data is immutable, use:

```
record Coordinate ( double x , double y ) {}
```

## `record`

Java 16 brought the [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature.

A record is a briefer way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You merely declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the default constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

This feature makes creating a class such as yours much more convenient.

```
public record Coordinate ( double x , double y ) {}
```

If needed, you can override any of those methods. You can add more methods.

Just as an enum inherits from `Enum`, a record inherits from `Record`. And a record is implicitly `final`. So, no inheritance.

In Java 16+, a record can be defined locally as well as nested or separate. Ditto for enums and interfaces too, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Point2D.Double` directly when it will be converted later on anyways?